# Compress images for universal application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, compression, png

I'm working on Universal app with a lot of background images (total size of one set of background images is ~5Mb, 3 platforms * 2 orientations = 6 background images per screen), also there is keyframe animations and i want to make my application not so terrible big. What tricks did you use to make your images not too heavy?

My ideas:

- Universal images for iPad/iPhone 4? - I thought that if i'll use iPad images for iPhone 4 - it will look not bad.
- Square images instead of using Vert/Horiz background images.
- [Image packer](http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/optimize-and-compress-png-files/). I'm planning to compress all my images before adding into application. Does it work for you?

Comment: 2 extra ideas: use core graphics to crop/resize images for each platform, download content from web

Comment: 1 extra idea: use jpeg for background images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously it is always a trade-off between memory/speed/size. That in mind, you mentioned the same methods I personally use. This is how I see them:

**[PNG images]** (for speed) vs. **[JPEG images]** (for memory/size)

**[SQUARE images]** (for size) vs. **[INDIVIDUAL images]** (for memory/speed)

**[UNIVERSAL images]** (for size) vs. **[INDIVIDUAL images]** (for memory/speed)

**[CROP images]** (for memory/size) vs. **[REGULAR images]** (for speed)

**[STREAM images]** (for size) vs. **[INCLUDE images]** (for memory/speed)

With respect to the image packer, Xcode does its own compression and data stripping. I haven't heard much regarding how effective it is, though. I personally just open everything in Preview and re-save to check if it can be smaller.

The number one method (only if possible, obviously) is most definitely using stretchable images, either by fitting them to the bounds, or using `stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: topCapHeight:`
(but sadly is usually not an option, only for border/gradient backgrounds)

Comment: Yes, i see. But may be there is some another tricks to make app even more smaller?